# Mail.dll through proxy C#

Tags: c#, email

I have the following task: I should read e-mails from gmail and the computer is connected to the internet through proxy. Normally I would use mail.dll http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail like this:

```
    using (Imap imap = new Imap())
    {
        imap.ConnectSSL(_server);
        imap.Login(_user, _password);

        // Select the Inbox folder, ou can also select other folders.
        // E.g. Sent folder: imap.Select("Sent");
        imap.SelectInbox();

        // Find all unseen messages:
        List<long> uidList = imap.Search(Flag.All);


        // Download each message:
        foreach (long uid in uidList)
        {
            IMail email = new MailBuilder().CreateFromEml(
                imap.GetMessageByUID(uid));

            // Display email data, save attachments:
            ProcessMessage(email);                    
        }
        imap.Close(true);
    }
```

but what should I do when there's proxy and authorization required?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Mail.dll supports **SOCKS4**, **SOCKS4a**, **SOCKS5** and **HTTP** proxies:

```
ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
IProxyClient proxy = factory.CreateProxy(ProxyType.Socks5, "69.139.119.66", 1144);
Socket socket = proxy.Connect("imap.gmail.com", Imap.DefaultSSLPort);

using (Imap imap = new Imap())
{
    imap.AttachSSL(socket, "imap.gmail.com");

    // regular imap code

    imap.Close();
}
```

Remember to add reference to both Mail.dll and Proxy.dll.

You can download the latest version supporting proxies here:
http://www.limilabs.com/mail

Comment: Anybody using NuGet for downloading package. Mail.dll is available on NuGet but Proxy.dll is not. It is only available at mentioned link in above answer bundled with Mail.zip